# Make Java threads called through Rest API run synchronously

Tags: java, multithreading

I am invoking a Java thread through Rest API. When the user clicks on Process button this method is being called

```
@Override
    public String processTags(ServiceExecutionContext ctx, SetTag tags) throws ExecException {

        Thread t = new Thread(new TagService(customerId, tags));
        t.setName("Thread at "+new Date());
        t.start();
        return "Processing started in background";

    }
```

In the run method of TagService

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        ServiceExecutionContext ctx = null;
        try {
            ctx = getServiceExecutionContextForCustomer(this.customerId);
            performUpdate(ctx,this.tags)
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(ctx != null)
                ctx.teardownNormal();
        }
    }

public static void performUpdate(ServiceExecutionContext ctx, String tags){
       String q = "Select column1 from table where id=1";
       List<String>list = ctx.getSession().createQuery(q).list();
       String currentVal = list.get(0);
       String newVal = currentVal + tag;
       String q1 = "Update table set column1=?";
    ctx.getSession().createQuery(q1).setParameter(0,newVal).executeUpdate();

}
```

Suppose two users requested for process one after another. Thread-1 with value A and Thread-2 with value B. Thread-1 starts: get value from table say it is empty it puts value A, now before Thread-1 commits the transaction thread-2 starts . When thread-2 fetches the data value is still empty since thread-1 didn't commit its changes. So thread-2 it append B to the empty value.

And when both the threads commits transaction user will be expecting AB as the value but instead will be getting "B" . How can I handle this?

Comment: Lock the table row! A transaction should do this if you use it correctly. See [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).

Comment: I am using hibernate , can u help me with a link for the same?

Comment: See [`LockMode`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/LockMode.html).

Comment: If you are using Spring, you can annotate your function as @Transactional

Comment: I am not using spring. And when I lock the table row, I am getting lock wait time out exception

Comment: I am doing update using a single insert query INSERT INTO my_table (id,NAME,place) VALUES (1,"A","P1"),(2,"B","P2"),(3,"C","P3"),(4,"D","P4")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NAME=VALUES(NAME),place = VALUES(place); . How will I get Lock mode for this ?